# A group having prime order such that any normal subgroup of which lies in Z(G).

Tags: permutations

show that in a group G of order p^2 any normal subgroup of order p must lie in the center of G.

Comment: What have you tried? suppose $N\unlhd G$ with $|N|=p$ and $N\cap Z(G)= \{e\}$ then.. what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: I think there is some link between right or left cosets , commutativity of Z(G)

Comment: Note that we do not actually need the order to be $p^2$ for this. Any power of $p$ will do. I know two ways to do this, one using the normalizer/centralizer theorem, and the other by (slightly annoying) calculations. Have you heard of the normalizer/centralizer theorem?

Comment: NO.. i donot no that theorem...

Comment: this question is from the book Topics in Algebra by I.N.Herstein

Comment: If $x$ is an element in the given subgroup and $g$ is an element from the group, then you know that $gxg^{-1}$ is some power of $x$. You need to show that this power must be $1$ mod $p$. Note what hapens if you instead conjugate by some power of $g$, and use that $g^{p^k}$ is the identity for some $k$.

Comment: The title and body don't match. The title says the group has order $p$, the body, $p^2$. Can you edit please for clarity?

Answer (score 0):

Prove the following  :

1. If $|G| = p^n$, then $Z(G) \neq \{e\}$ (Use the class equation)
2. If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.
3. If $|G| = p^2$, then $G$ is abelian. Hence, $Z(G) = G$

Conclude whatever you want :)

Comment: he said he  do not know class equation... I do not think this would help him any how..